# Do I have to install Rails on every new project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a beginner-level question.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

I copied a project (created on Rails 4 using the `rails new` command) from Dropbox to my local environment, where I have previously install Rails 4 and up-to-date Ruby and RVM, went to project's directory, typed rails server and got

*The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:*

*sudo apt-get install rails*

I ran `gem install rails` instead.

Will I have to run `gem install rails` on every project's directory? I thought the Rails install was a general and accessible on my whole environment.

The project was created using the same Ruby version, but on a MacOS X system.

The project is a static web brochure and has no database configuration.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i advice you using "apt-get install rails" instead of "sudo apt-get install rails" for installing rails. You might have issues later on. So for now run "sudo apt-get remove rails" and then run "apt-get install rails".

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou I ran `gem install rails` instead.

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou: You can't do `apt-get install` since you are not root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to install Rails on every project, but the gems that you need for that project.

With `bundle install` you install all the gems that you specify in `Gemfile`.

If you want to avoid reinstall the gems every time you change project, I suggest you to have a better look to RVM: it has got an opt called gemset (https://rvm.io/gemsets), if you use it you just need to switch your gemset:

```
rvm gemset use yourgemset
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: the project came with a _.ruby-gemset_ and a _.ruby-version_ files which point to default gems and ruby 2.1.0 which is installed. Yet, after copying the project from my Mac to my Ubuntu, it asks to install rails everytime.

Comment: mhh, in that case I don't know. Once to avoid similar problem in my Mac I installed Vagrant to recreate the very same environment, but I know that is a bit drastic :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the correct version of Ruby - the same version that you'd installed Rails into - with `rvm list`.

You likely have two of them (since you have such an issue) - the system Ruby and the RVM-installed Ruby. And likely RVM didn't engage and hook up the correct path to the `rails` executable, thus the error.

This should fix the issue:

```
rvm use whatever-ruby-you-had-installed-rails-into
```

Where `whatever-ruby-you-had-installed-rails-into` is a string like `ruby-2.1.0-p0` taken from the `rvm list` output.

To make RVM retain Ruby version for the project.

```
echo whatever-ruby-you-had-installed-into >.ruby-version
```

in your project's path.

Comment: `ruby -v`: **ruby 2.1.0p0**
`rvm info`: **ruby-2.1.0**

The original project was created on a MacOS X system though, could that be an issue?

Comment: It shouldn't; what does `gem list rails` say?

Comment: It outputs two lines: rails (4.0.2) _and_
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)

Comment: No, I ran bundle install and some gems were not installed, `bundle exec rails server` prompts: _Could not find arel-4.0.1 in any of the sources_ and
_Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems._

Answer (score 1):

So after a few hours of testing, reproducing the problem, and reading (the other answers inclusive) I got the solution as follows:

Short answer: No. Rails needs to be installed only once.

Long answer: This problem occurred because of a default setting on Terminal that prevents the system from using RVM installations of ruby and rails. The solution is to [integrate RVM with gnome-terminal](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal) as described in the RVM website.

1. With terminal window active, go to the menu at the top bar
2. Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command tab
3. Check the **Run command as a login shell** box
4. Restart Terminal and make sure your gemset and ruby version are set
5. `rails server` should now work as expected (you might be prompted to run `bundle install` before Rails can actually run fine, follow the promtp).

I am still learning to work with Ruby on Rails, so any inputs, clarifications, or additional information on the issue is more than welcome.